# Is it legal to put a traffic cone on the side of the road to protect property?

Tags: england-and-wales, traffic, is-x-legal

Does the law in England allow a traffic cone to be placed on the road next to property to help warn drivers and to protect the property?

Comment: What property? Do you mean like a suitcase waiting to be picked up by a taxi cab? Or do you mean to keep cars from cutting a corner short and driving on your grass?

Comment: What I mean is a cone to keep heavy vehicles from hitting the wall of a property

Comment: Is "the wall" a building wall, or a fence around a yard?

Comment: It's a building wall made of bricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is it legal to put a traffic cone on the side of the road to protect property?**

**Probably not** on the limited information available, especially as there are other remedies available such as fixing reflectors etc to the wall or requesting you local [Highway Authority](https://www.fillthathole.org.uk/authorities/list) to take appropriate action.

There is the potential for an offence under [s.137(1) of the Highways Act 1980](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1980/66/section/137?timeline=false):

> (1) If a person, without lawful authority or excuse, in any way wilfully obstructs the free passage along a highway he is guilty of an offence...

Notwithstanding a cone may (or may not) be visible to other road users there is also the potential for an offence under [s.22A(1)(a) of the Road Traffic Act 1988](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/52/section/22A?timeline=false)

> (1) A person is guilty of an offence if he intentionally and without lawful authority or reasonable cause—
>
> (a) causes anything to be on or over a road, or
>
> ...
>
> in such circumstances that it would be obvious to a reasonable person that to do so would be dangerous.

*Whether any action will be taken is another question.*

Comment: I don't think to plant a traffic cone at the side of a road is "obvious to a reasonable person that to do so would be dangerous."

Comment: Hence "*potential*"

Comment: ...And it's not at the side of the road, it's **on it** (as per the OP)