# Parking on the road and private traffic cones on a road in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, traffic

Outside a private residence in the UK, the road is a slight curve and is narrow where 2 cars can only just get past each other. It is a road between two villages.

Is it legal to park a car there which can obscure traffic sight lines to the extent that some passing cars brake hard when there is oncoming traffic?

Is it legal to park a car on the curved road if there is a parking layby opposite the house which is offroad and has been used for 40 years?

Is it legal to park a car on a curved road which then causes traffic, including heavy buses, to use part of a neighbour's driveway for passing purposes which has caused the driveway to sink in one place?

Is it legal to put a traffic cone in front of and sometimes to the side of the car on the curved road which reduces road width further?

Note: I am aware of [this thread](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/64451/is-it-legal-to-put-a-traffic-cone-on-the-side-of-the-road-to-protect-property), but that seems to be a little more specific for (building) property.

Answer (score 3):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

The OP's linked question seems to cover the placement of cones on the road.

The relevant legislation (from which some of the Highway Code derives its rules) and potential offences for the parking described are:

- Wilful obstruction, contrary to [section 137](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1980/66/section/137?timeline=false), Highways Act 1980:

> (1) If a person, without lawful authority or excuse, in any way wilfully obstructs the free passage along a highway he is guilty of an offence and liable to a fine not exceeding level 3 on the standard scale.([*i.e. £1,000*](https://www.sentencingcouncil.org.uk/explanatory-material/magistrates-court/item/fines-and-financial-orders/approach-to-the-assessment-of-fines-2/9-maximum-fines/))

And

- Leaving vehicles in dangerous positions contrary to [section 22](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/52/section/22?timeline=false), Road Traffic Act 1988:

> If a person in charge of a vehicle causes or permits the vehicle or a trailer drawn by it to remain at rest on a road in such a position or in such condition or in such circumstances as to involve a danger of injury to other persons using the road, he is guilty of an offence. ([*also £1,000 maximum fine*](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/53/schedule/2/part/I?timeline=false))

Answer (score 1):

Answering one of multiple questions about curved roads:

> Is it legal to park a car there which can obscure traffic sight lines to the extent that some passing cars brake hard when there is oncoming traffic?

The [Highway Code](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/waiting-and-parking-238-to-252) rule 243 says

> **DO NOT stop or park:**
>
> - . . .
> - on a bend
> - . . .

and other places where you would be causing an obstruction. Where the Highway code says "DO NOT" or "MUST NOT" this is a legal requirement (otherwise is says "*should* not...").

Comment: Does the Highway Code specify the curvature of the road needed to constitute a bend? At normal speed you cannot see the exit of the bend when you enter in this case. One driver used to start beeping his horn before getting to the corner and kept beeping it all the way through due to the exit not being visible when you enter.

Comment: It doesn't specify the curvature, but if there is limited line of sight I suppose that a 'curve' is a 'bend'. If you read the whole list of forbidden places to stop, you'll see that it's about causing obstructions (sometimes where there is specific signage).

Comment: "MUST NOT" indicates a legal requirement, though it isn't one itself - the Highway Code will specify the relevant legislation (as can be seen in the online copy at gov.uk and as mentioned in the Wikipedia entry). "DO NOT" and "should not" are advisory rules. No legislation is specified at rule 243 in the current edition, but rule 242 (a "MUST NOT") is looking good for this. In practice things listed at Rule 243 are likely to be taken as indication of compliance, or otherwise, with rule 242, Section 22 of the Road Traffic Act 1988 and the Road Vehicles (Construction and Use) Regulations 1986.

Comment: Rule 242 says: You MUST NOT leave your vehicle or trailer in a dangerous position or where it causes any unnecessary obstruction of the road.'

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere : So what does **'obstruction'** mean? Does that only mean blocking the road fully so nothing can pass? Or does it mean in this specific case where it blocks half the road where cars/buses screech to a halt when they suddenly see something overtaking the parked car? Or is it the key word **'unnecessary'** in this context? It is 'unnecessary' because when the car is parked in the layby across the road as it had been for 40 years, it caused no obstruction whatsoever?

Comment: @Rewind - It (both the definition of "obstruction" and the offence of "unnecessary obstruction") are not very well specified, so these may become something for a court to decide  - which is worth bearing in mind if someone accuses you of it. But presence or absence of other parking aren't likely to be relevant in determining necessity : the driver still didn't "have to" park where they did.